# Ambiguous to-infinitive: "Obama rejects G20 pressure to abandon Syria air strike plan."

Tags: sentence-construction, ambiguity

> Obama rejects G20 pressure to abandon Syria air strike plan.

I think this news headline is ambiguous because the infinitive clause could attach to either *G20's pressure* as its complement(?), or to *Obama*, in which case it would have the sense of *in order to*.

**Can you suggest a fix that eliminates the ambiguity?**

Comment: It's a headline; they're rarely shining examples of perfect sentences. They're usually cut short and written to catch your eye. If a headline reads as ambiguous, reading the article should clear up the confusion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to fix the ambiguity while keeping it short would be:

> Obama rejects G20 pressure; will not abandon Syria air strike plan

I think it's pretty clear that this is the meaning.

Comment: that's a nice way to rephrase. +1

Answer (score 0):

Edit after Andrew Leach's comment: "*Obama ignores G20; attack on Syria still possible*"

---

A fix can be: *Obama snubs G20; attack on Syria very likely*

Comment: That is not equivalent. The original says Obama has not abandoned a plan, your fix says an attack is likely. Also, the original does not say he snubbed them - your fix indicates more hostility to G20 than the original does.

Comment: But if he hasn't abandoned the plan to attack, doesn't that mean that attack is likely?

Comment: Not necessarily. "Not abandoning" is more ambiguous than "is very likely".

Comment: Maybe you are right.

Comment: You might tone it down with "Obama ignores G20; attack on Syria still possible," but that still places an interpretation on the headline which might not be justified.

Comment: Nice, I'll edit my answer.